# How to change button in notification?

Tags: android, notifications, foreground-service

I'm making my foreground service notification for controlling features on my device. Now I have notification with FlashLight button. Moreover, I can handling this button with PendingIntent. And I want to make button with another color when it's pushed. How can I do that? Probably, I missed something evident. Maybe, I can do it via context in onReceive method, but I still don't know how to do that. Please, help me.[image: notification]

```
//It's method in Service that I started from MainActivity
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Notification notification;
    //Create notification builder
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification = notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.white_bulb)
                    .setContentTitle("My Title")
                    .setContentText("My Text")
                    .build();
    //create a remoteViews to this notification
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notificationlayout);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.white_bulb);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Popup Notification");
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "");
    //create a pendingIntent for button in my notification
    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, SwitchButtonListener.class);
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.switchLight, pendingSwitchIntent);
    notification.contentView = remoteViews;
    //actually run the notification
    startForeground(notificationID, notification);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}  
   //It's method in SwitchButtonListener.class that run when I push the button     
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (!isFlash){
        holdCamera();
        runFlashLight();
        isFlash = true;
    }else {
        stopFlashLight();
        unholdCamera();
        isFlash = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. My mistake - use Button with setBackground() for image. In this case remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.switchLight, R.drawable.blue_bulb) throw fatal error. Solution - use ImageButton and setImageViewResource() will works right. And actually answer for my question:
For changing the button in notification -
1. store an instance of NotificationCompat.Builder that builded my notification, notificationID and RemoteViews (my notification content).
2.Change button src with remoteViews.setImageViewResource()
3.Via notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuider.build());
So, actually, there is no way to change button in notification. We should recreate whole notification with small different.
First paragraph I did with static variables in PopupService. As you can see buttons have another view.[image: it's work fine]